# Modal view does not fire from child controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

My `MainViewController` loads another view modally.

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *uiViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splashViewController"];
    [uiViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCustom];
    [uiViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:uiViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I load the `MainViewController` directly from the `AppDelegate`, the modal view is loaded.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If I load the `MainViewController` as a child controller of another controller, then the modal view fails to load.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.drawerViewController.leftViewController = self.leftDrawerViewController;
    self.drawerViewController.centerViewController = self.mainViewController;
    self.drawerViewController.animator = self.drawerAnimator;

    UIViewController *rootController = self.drawerViewController;
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The main view still loads. It's only that the modal view is not created.

What's causing the problem and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not present another view controller from viewDidLoad method ,

by that time , current view is NOT finished with its view-hieararchy changes ,

You can present new viewcontroller after viewDidAppear is called ,
so you can move that code to viewDidAppear

Comment: Looks as if it's working now but another part seems to be failing.

Comment: just make sure you are not presenting multiple view controllers at once , or you are not presenting and dismissing them at the same time